# C# java script code for checkexistring file in a folder code using uploadify

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am able to upload file(s) from system to server using uploadify control(www.uploadify.com). Everything is working fine but thing is that I am not getting how to check the file existing or not in the server. I need help from you that how to check existing file(s) using java script or C# before uploading file(s) to server. I have code for checkexisting in php but I want in C# or java script so kindly please kindly do needful.

Thanks
PBN

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but checking if a file exists with C# could be done with:

```
string path = @"C:\yaddayadda\file.txt";
bool fileExists = File.Exists(path);
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

But perhaps you were asking something else? In that case please clarify.